# Best weapons types for certain vocations

Tags: dragon-quest-9

My question is to know the best weapon type for a mage useing lots of mana and magic(I use wand), and the best weapon type for a healing , reviving strategy minstrel. (I use a sword , currently have inferno blade)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "healing, reviving strategy"? Providing detail may help the community provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This has been unanswered for a while. I think I can offer some guidance.

For a Mage, the best weapon type for your setup is a Wand because you get to recover MP when it strikes, plus you get MP boosts when you put points into its skill.

A Minstrel who heals as a main strategy should probably use Fans. You can get some good ones that heal MP-free when used as an item in battle (such as the Friendly Fan). Remember though that Minstrels are jack-of-all-trades and if you don't switch strategies often then consider a Priest.

Do play with putting these two in the back row. As these two are not using physical attacks you can hit from distance.

Having said that the game logic is said to be broken by some, that the back row makes no difference to attack strength only reducing the chance of being targeted, so it won't matter according to them.